# How to assign value to Address , Country and City

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Here is classes

-Person
-User
-City
-Country
-Address

Person has complex properties of (Address),
Address has complex Properties of (Country , City)
Class User inherited from Person class

scenario:-

I want to create a signup view inwhich i want to assign values to Address , country , city. How can i do it.

Below is the detail of classes

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    { }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private Gender gender;

    public virtual Gender Gender
    {
        get { return gender; }
        set { gender = value; }
    }
    private ICollection<ContactNumber> contactNumber;

    public virtual ICollection<ContactNumber> ContactNumber
    {
        get { return contactNumber; }
        set { contactNumber = value; }
    }


    private Address address;

    public virtual Address Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }


    private DateTime dateOfBirth;

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return dateOfBirth; }
        set { dateOfBirth = value; }
    }

    private string picture;

    public string Picture
    {
        get { return picture; }
        set { picture = value; }
    }
}

public class User : Person
{
    public User() : base()
    { }

    private ICollection<Role> roles;

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles
    {
        get { return roles; }
        set { roles = value; }
    }

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string email;                        

    [Required()]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }

    private string loginId;

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Login")]
    public string LoginId
    {
        get { return loginId; }
        set { loginId = value; }
    }

    private string password;

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return password; }
        set { password = value; }
    }
    private string repassword;

    [Required()]        
    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]        
    [Compare("Password")]               
    public string Repassword    
    {
      get { return repassword; }
      set { repassword = value; }
    }
    private string secretQuestion;

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Secret Question")]
    public string SecretQuestion
    {
        get { return secretQuestion; }
        set { secretQuestion = value; }
    }
    private string secretAnswer;

    [Required()]
    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    public string SecretAnswer
    {
        get { return secretAnswer; }
        set { secretAnswer = value; }
    }

    private string photoUrl;

    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string PhotoUrl
    {
        get { return photoUrl; }
        set { photoUrl = value; }
    }
}


public class Country
{
    public Country()
    { }

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    //private string flagUrl;
}

public class City
{
    public City()
    { }

    private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
    private Country country;

    public virtual Country Country
    {
        get { return country; }
        set { country = value; }
    }
}
```

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to create a view to include all these classes as the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click on your action method for your signup page in your controller and select **Add View** In the dialog that appears you can choose to make the view **strongly typed**. Select your `User` class and visual studio will scaffold a lot of the code needed.

If you need more help in working with MVC [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc) is a good place to start.